# Find and replace a string into a path in batch

Tags: search, batch-file, replace

I am trying a batch file which replaces a changing text named X by a static text 'English' into the path

```
  Y:\SUT\ISTQB\Board\X\Dashboard\Open
```

About the position of the X text, it is always surrounded with 'Board' and 'Dashboard'.

In the path below, the current below text for the given path is 'X=Language' and my goal is finally to get 'X=English' each time of course!

```
   Y:\SUT\ISTQB\Board\Language\Dashboard\Open
```

The string of replacement is read from a file. This file only contains 'English'

Is that possible to find a solution through a pipe with the 'find' command?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET mypath=Y:\SUT\ISTQB\Board\X\Dashboard\Open
FOR /f %%i IN (languagefile.txt) DO SET language=%%i
SET mypath=%mypath:\Dashboard\=*%
SET mypath=%mypath:\Board\=*%
FOR /f "tokens=1,3delims=*" %%i IN ("%mypath%") DO SET mypath=%%i\Board\%language%\Dashboard\%%j
ECHO %mypath%
```

"*" chosen because it cannot occur in a pathname.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "string=Y:\SUT\ISTQB\Board\Language\Dashboard\Open"
set "search=%string:*\Board\=%"
for /f "delims=\" %%i in ("%search%") do set "search=%%i"
set "string=!string:%search%=English!"
echo %string%
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say one fundamental thing: 'Language' is a changing text which is always located between 'Board' and 'Dashboard'. So I have updated my question. Thanks.